# Is it possible to tag an already masked text in python?

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I'm trying to preprocess a text file for NLP and in this effort we are tagging various items such as dates, addresses and sensitive personal information (SPI). The problem is the text has already masked some of these information. For example:

Jan 6, xxxx or (xxx)xxx-1234

My question is, is it possible to use regular expression in python to unmask them so that we can proceed with tagging them properly?
So I need something like this:

Jan 6, 1111 or (111)111-1234

To tag them as #US_DATE and #PHONE

I've tried simple possible solutions such as:

```
re.sub(r'xx', '11', '(xxx)xxx-1234')
re.sub(r'xx+', '11', 'January 9 xxxx')
```

but neither give me the right pattern!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps one option is to match the different formats that you have using an alternation and use re.sub with a callback to replace all the `x` characters with 1.

For the pattern I have used [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to specify what you would allow to match, but you could update that to make it more specific.

```
\b[A-Za-z]{3,} [a-zA-Z\d]{1,2},? [a-zA-Z\d]{4}\b|\([a-zA-Z\d]+\)[a-zA-Z\d]{3}-[a-zA-Z\d]{4}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG3UvE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ct55ji)

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"\b[A-Za-z]{3,} [a-zA-Z\d]{1,2},? [a-zA-Z\d]{4}\b|\([a-zA-Z\d]+\)[a-zA-Z\d]{3}-[a-zA-Z\d]{4}\b"
test_str = ("Jan 6, xxxx or (xxx)xxx-1234\n"
    "Jan 16, xxxx or (xxx)xxx-1234\n"
    "January 9 xxxx\n"
    "(xxx)xxx-1234")
matches = re.sub(regex, lambda x: x.group().replace('x', '1'),  test_str)
print(matches)
```

Result

```
Jan 6, 1111 or (111)111-1234
Jan 16, 1111 or (111)111-1234
January 9 1111
(111)111-1234
```

Comment: tnx, that's a fairly good answer and I started building on that, but it turned out a simple regex = r"\b[x]{2,20}" would give me what I need!

Comment: That will replace all 2 - 20 times `x` in the content and will also match `don't remove the xxxxxxxx part`.

Comment: Well, I do want those $xxxxx$ to be matched as well! sure, will mark it as the solution. :)